# How to remove space before and after any numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How to remove space before and after any numbers?
for e.g. `"     3,340  "`.

I want this number to look like this `"3,340"`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9).

Example:  =TRIM(" 3,340 ") results in "3,340".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Steven for your response. I already tried TRIM function but dint work, however now I have the answer to this question now, so I wanted it to share with you all. Below is the combination of 2 function, it gave me desired output.

=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(D2,CHAR(160),""))